# How to init a macro on mousedown in MS Word in VBA?

Tags: vba, ms-word

In MS word, I'm trying to init a macro when a textbox is selected.

[image]

Textbox above is "Text Box 89". I can't find any specific name reference to it other than this.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/access.textbox.mousedown

Allow the same principle

```
Private Sub textbox_MouseDown(Button As Integer, Shift As Integer, X As Single, Y As Single)

    If Button = acLeftButton Then
        MsgBox "You pressed the left button."
    End If

End Sub
```

On clicking the box, how do I init this macro?

Comment: ActiveX controls have various events you can handle, including `MouseDown` but also `Enter` (and `Exit`), which seems relevant here. Looks like your textbox isn't an ActiveX textbox.

Comment: How are you inserting the text box - which commands are you using? The kind of text box that can use this event is found in Developer/Controls/Legacy Tools/ActiveX.